# What is relationship between Express routes and client routes in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm a NextJS newbie and trying to understand the relationship between routes defined in Express and those defined in the 'client', React portion of NextJS. Specifically, if one defines a route on the Express side, such as

```
router.get("/aLonelyRoute",(req,res)=> {
   res.end("You made it!")
})
```

that doesn't have a corresponding 'page' on the client side (we have the following pages in our React app

```
pages/index.js
pages/something.js
pages/another.js
```

), if a request is made to `/aLonelyRoute` from the browser, will this always be served from the Express server, never rendered from the client?

Also, is it true that if the Express server serves a page that *does *correspond to a route reflected on the 'client' side, then `app.render` *automagically* serves it either from the server or renders it from the client, depending:

```
router.get("/something",(req,res)=> {
       app.render(req,res,'something',query)
    })
```

Am I on the right path in understanding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `express` for a custom SSR(Server Side Rendering). - In a simple way when you refresh the page or type the URL in url bar and press enter. Express and `Next.js` router work together to serve the page however it depends on what kind of render has been asked for. if it is a Client side rendering, then next.js will take over and if SSR, then Express will take over first(Next.js will ask for express to take over).

```
server.get('/p/:id', (req, res) => {
  const actualPage = '/post'
  const queryParams = { title: req.params.id }
  app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams)
})
```

In above example, if there is a client side rendering, user will go something like `/post/a-cool-post` but server will receive `/post?id=a-cool-post` which was **masked** to `/p/a-cool-post`. Note that `/p/...` doesn't exists. it is a mask URL. look at **as** in this example.

```
<Link as={`/p/${post.id}`} href={`/post?title=${post.title}`}>
  <a>{post.title}</a>
</Link>
```

Long story short, it means we are asking express (in this case server side rendering) if a route is something like `/p/a-cool-post`, go and give us `/post/a-cool-post` which is a client side rendering. so the route in client and server will be the same.

*First question*:
`/aLonelyRoute` is only in express and there is no code to tell what is it equivalent in client-die. so it will only render from Server.

*Second question*:
Yes it is correct. Depends what user ask for, if they type url in url bar and press enter 
and refresh the page, then express and if you use **Next Router** for routing, then it will be client side.