# How to route in Node.js/React.js Web App?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a Next.js Frontend - Express.js Backend Web App.
I have some problems with routing. In the official documentation of Next.js, I read that if we use a custom server, we have to disable the automatic routing that uses the folder /pages to work.

module.exports = {
useFileSystemPublicRoutes: false,
}

But at this point, how can I route the pages. I'm thinking to still use the /pages folder to group the several pages.

How can i route from backend? Have I to import in some way the javascript
pages? Like this code...

router.get('/users', function (req, res) { "import Next.js page" });

Or it's antoher type of process like use "react-router".

Can anyone give me an example of the best choice? Thanks

Comment: Please update your question with code samples and a specific description of the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [next-routes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-routes).

```
// server.js
const next = require('next')
const routes = require('./routes')
const app = next({dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'})
const handler = routes.getRequestHandler(app)
 
// With express
const express = require('express')
app.prepare().then(() => {
  express().use(handler).listen(3000)
})
 
// Without express
const {createServer} = require('http')
app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer(handler).listen(3000)
})
```

and your routes.js file

```
const routes = module.exports = require('next-routes')()

routes
    .add('about')
    .add('blog', '/blog/:slug')
    .add('user', '/user/:id', 'profile')
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I have only a little question..... In general when is better route with backend and not with frontend?

Comment: I would say that it depends on SSR or client SR. Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54285789/7622832